# Is there a way to query fonts that support a particular Unicode range?

Tags: fonts

I would like to find out which fonts actually have glyphs in a particular Unicode range (such as Cyrillic, Armenian, Georgian etc). I am familiar with Character Map and Font Matrix programs, but there is no way to make a particular Unicode range "stick" in order to see which fonts do support it. Is there a better way than to have to click through all the fonts and eyeball all the ranges in the list box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `fc-list` tool to list fonts matching various patterns.  One such pattern is to query fonts for their language coverage.

To query for fonts supporting Armenian (which has a two letter ISO language code `hy`), run the following:

```
fc-list :lang=hy
```

The same should work for other languages you are interested in.